# Backend user restricted to one language should not be able to create content for all languages

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have a backend user with permissions to work with only one language. But this backend user still can create or switch content to the "All languages" language.

How can I disable the "All languages" option for this user.

Or how can I disable it at all? We do not need it at all.

**My attempt so far:**

I edited the configuration for `sys_language_uid` in  `typo3\sysext\frontend\Configuration\TCA\tt_content.php`:

```
'sys_language_uid' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'special' => 'languages',
       /* 'items' => array(
            array(
                'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
                -1,
                'flags-multiple'
            ),
        ),*/
        'default' => 0,
    )
),
```

In all normal tt_content elements the "all" language is not available anymore. But there are two drawbacks:

- It overwrites a core file and is not update-safe.
- It only disable the "all" language in tt_content elements, not in other elements from extensions (e.g. news).

Comment: your backend user must be have a group so did you restrict permission for that group?

Comment: yes and he only have the perminission for that 1 language. But he can still create content for "All". I can not find anything in the group settings. Maybe there is a typoscript way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove options from TCEFORM select boxes using Page TSConfig:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.sys_language_uid.removeItems = -1
```

You need to have such a configuration for every table affected:

```
TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.sys_language_uid.removeItems = -1
```

Unfortunately there is no hook in the core to influence the language list of a select box with special type `languages`. If you really need this low-level, you could XCLASS `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormDataProvider\DatabaseSystemLanguageRow.php` and remove the `[All languages]` language there.